# TCS3200 collor sensor with arduino r3 uno

Tags: arduino

I am trying to wire up the TCS3200 color sensor for arduino uno R3 and I am having issues. I have checked many documents on the web and they all have different ways of wiring. Some document set OE pin on TCS3200 to ground on the Arduino, and other don't use the OE pin. Some document set s0= Arduino pin 2, s1= Arduino pin 3, s2= Arduino pin 4, s3=Arduino pin 5, and out pin to Arduino pin 10. Other documents have a different pin wiring configurations.

Hence i was wonder what is the correct way to wire TCS3200 color sensor to the Arduino? I have tried a lot of wiring configuration but the LEDs on TCS3200 won't light up. Does anyone have a solution?

Here is my code:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT); //s0
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT); //s1
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT); //s2
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT); //s3
  pinMode(10, INPUT); //out
  digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(3,LOW);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(4,LOW);
  digitalWrite(5,LOW);
  Serial.println("red");
  Serial.print(pulseIn(10, LOW));
  Serial.println();
  delay(100);

  digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
  Serial.println("green");
  Serial.print(pulseIn(10, LOW));
  Serial.println();
  delay(100);

  digitalWrite(4,LOW);
  digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
  Serial.println("blue");
  Serial.print(pulseIn(10, LOW));
  Serial.println();
  delay(100);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: it does not matter which of Arduinos I/O pins you use as long as you use the device as documented in the datasheet... did you provide power to the chip?

Comment: Yes I provided 5v from my Arduino to the chip. Should I provide 3.3v instead?

Comment: how can you possibly ask this question? maybe you should read datasheets befor you fry your stuff. so no you 5V is ok.